# Express 4.7.2 render views

Tags: node.js, express

Apparently in Express 4.7.2 render does not explicit ends the execution, that means:

on Express 4.2

```
res.render('path/to/view');
res.render('path/to/view');
```

Render display the first view and ends the execution.

on Express 4.7.2

```
res.render('path/to/view');
res.render('path/to/view');
```

Throws 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error, for example:

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res) {
   if ( someFancyValidation ) {
      res.render('error_view');
   }
   res.render('succes_view');
});
```

We need an explicit 'return' statement in order to get the desirable result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res) {
  if ( someFancyValidation ) {
     res.render('error_view');
  }
  else//you missed this
     res.render('succes_view');
});
```

You can't render twice for a single call.

Comment: yep, that makes sense now with 4.7, express 4.2 saves me a lot of else statements, I liked.

Comment: you can always use `return` after render if that makes things any better :/